# Java path for eclipse Rhostudio on OSX 10.6

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, path

I'm following the Rhomobile guide to [installing java](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/install#java-development-kit-jdk).

I believe my system java path is: `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` As you can see in the screen shot below. The rake task aborts because something is either wrong with my path or system installation of Java. You can see that the instructions on Rhomobile are vague, and the apple instructions are equally vague. I'm relying on your expertise with this. :)

What is the proper path and or how do I install Java to compile android applications?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the help page you point to, they show the path in question as being the location of the actual executables, which is more like `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/` . I generally use `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/bin`, which points to the same place but it's a bit more robust to version bumps.

Comment: thanks! it worked like a charm and I have a chemistry app written in ruby on my android!